# mysql syntax error in prepared statements or invalid parameter number pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

when i run the code below:

```
$sql = "SELECT Id from users where Phone_number =:df";
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindParam(":df","093057789655",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I get the error of SQL syntax error and it's got a problem with that ":df".

when I wrap it in single quotations, `':df'`, the SQL syntax error is gone but I'm given the gift of a pdo error.

```
$sql = "SELECT Id from users where Phone_number =':df'";
           $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
           $stmt->bindParam(":df","093057789655",PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The error is 'Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' which I think stems from the fact that pdo can't recognize `':df'` as a parameter. Thus, it throws this error.

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Never wrap parameters in quotes, they'll be interpreted as a string and not a placeholder. I'd suggest adding a space between `=:`. If that still does not work, please provide the full error message.

Comment: You're also not executing this query. Are you getting an error when you run `prepare()`?

Comment: @aynber yessss yesss that's it. so simple. thank youuuu. please kindly submit this as an answer so I can set my question as answered.